# Ruboto: won't detect Android SDK platform-tools

Tags: android, ruboto

I need some help with Ruboto..

So I want to start doing some Android development using Ruboto. Here are the steps I took:

1. installed the android sdk
2. installed the sdk addons tools and platform-tools
3. installed jruby using `rvm install`
4. installed ruboto using `gem install`
5. add the android sdk-tools and platform-tools directory to my PATH in my .bashrc file using:
   `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/prem/android-sdks/tools:/Users/prem/android-sdks/platform-tools`
6. created a ruboto project using `ruboto gen ..`
7. start an emulator using `emulator -avd emulator-name`
8. inside the project directory I run `rake install start` but I get the following error:

> $ rake install start
>
> You need to install the Android SDK Platform-tools!

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I did the same thing on Ubuntu 12.04, I get the same error (need to install platform-tools!).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to Scott for posting a solution to this on my question on Google groups here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ruboto/OI6MobKAiGY

If this problem persists, the way to solve it is to install the latest version of Ruboto (pre-release candidate) by running:

> gem install ruboto --pre

That solved it for me!

Comment: Mine still tells me 'You need to install the Android SDK Platform-tools!' I wonder if there is a way to use --trace to get more information?

Comment: Try deleting the app and recreating it using `ruboto gen..`. You must use the new version of ruboto to generate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I started the project over from scratch and everything seems to be ok now.  Whew!  That was a little scary

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem.  Try this suggestion from the Ruboto user group.  It looks like the build tools folder structure was reorganized.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ruboto/OI6MobKAiGY

Comment: Thanks @joelbyler !. So I deleted my android-sdk and replaced it with a homebrew insatll (`brew install android-sdk`). Then I added the location to my `$PATH`. Now when I run `ruboto setup` it says `android-sdk not found, would you like to install sdk 10?`. However, homebrew installed the sdk, version **17**!. Anything missing?